# pip install mercurial error

Tags: python, mercurial, pip

I am on a server with no root access and I was having a lot of trouble trying to get mercurial installed because not all the python libraries were available (like osutil). I then tried:

```
pip install mercurial
```

It ran and did some stuff, then exited on the following error:

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/users/aas62/opt/mercurial-3.3-rc/build/mercurial/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-JnShsv-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Unexpectedly though, mercurial seems to work and is installed. I even ran

```
hg debuginstall
```

and it returned no errors. Is everything ok or could it crash in the future and mess up my repos?

The full log and error message is here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/texasflood/configs/b7b206cd6464a92b1d157e28f7cb19107fd755ae/pip.log

Comment: you need the sudo permission

Comment: If you try `which hg` and it shows it installed outside of your home directory it might have been installed already. If they have virtualenv installed it might be better to set one up instead.

Comment: @cloisteredmonkey it says /users/aas62/bin/hg. The only thing that I have noticed doesn't work is going `import mercurial` in python. That's not an issue for me as I won't be using any extensions.

Comment: @StackBox I know, but I don't have sudo permission.

Comment: try `pip install mercurial --user`

Comment: though virtualenv or pyenv may solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your installation crashed towards the very end, when creating the `mercurial` directory in the system-wide `dist-packages`.

Everything else before that looks like it worked, which would explain why you can run `hg`.

Since you don't have `sudo` permissions, you can try to install the module in your home directory rather than system-wide:

```
pip install --user mercurial
```